# JSF 2.0 and hibernate adding new objects to a postgresql database

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2

I'm writing a JSF 2.0 application with Hibernate and Postgresql database. My problem is quite poor understanding on how to handle session with Hibernate when inserting data into more than one table at a time. I have a method savePerson. The method is called as many times as there are addresses submitted by a user but the object Person is only created once. The method savePerson then calls the method addAddress. The code looks like this:

```
public Person savePerson(Person p, String address) {

        Transaction tx = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        if (p == null) {
             = new Person();

            try {
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(p);
                tx.commit();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
                    try {

                        tx.rollback();
                    } catch (HibernateException e1) {
                    }

                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }

        int id = p.getId();
        addAddress(4, id, address);

        return p;
    }
```

And the method addAddress:

```
public void addAddress(int table_id, int row_id, String address) {

        Transaction tx = null;
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Address a = new Address(table_id, row_id, address);

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(a);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("first try");

            if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
                System.out.println("first try if");
                try {
                    System.out.println("first try if try");

                    tx.rollback();
                } catch (HibernateException e1) {

                }
                // throw again the first exception
                throw e;
            }
            throw e;
        }
```

But I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
```

So what is the proper way of opening and closing session when inserting the data into more than one table at a time?

Best Regards,
sass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`TransactionException`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/TransactionException.html) *indicates that a transaction could not be begun, committed or rolled back*. But providing the full stacktrace would probably helpful to fully understand the problem.

That being said, while you can create multiple (serial) `Transaction` from a single `Session`, there is IMO a major flaw in your design. If you need to insert both the `Person` and the `Address`, you should very likely do it in a single unit of work. With your current approach, adding an `Address` can fail and leave a freshly inserted `Person` in an inconsistent state.

> So what is the proper way of opening and closing session when inserting the data into more than one table at a time?

Do it in a single transaction.

And if you want to remove the transaction management from your methods, you should consider using the [Open Session In View](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView) pattern, as suggested by [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778325/jsf-2-0-and-hibernate-adding-new-objects-to-a-postgresql-database/3778452#3778452). Unless you want finer grained transaction control of course.

#### Resources

- [Sessions and transactions](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Sessionsandtransactions)
- [Open Session in View](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView)

Comment: Thanks, Pascal. The problem is that I'm creating the Person object once but often need to add the address many times. can I still do it in one transaction?

Comment: If you're doing this in a single request, then you should certainly do it in a single transaction.

Comment: @sass Create the Person (and `save` it) only if required. I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A common practice would be to create a [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which opens the Hibernate  session before processing the request/response and commits and closes the session after processing the request/response. Finally map this `Filter` on `<servlet-name>` of `FacesServlet`. This is called *Open Session In View* or *Open Session Per Request*.

Spring provides such a filter out of the box, the [`OpenSessionInViewFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html), which is useful for the case that you're already using Spring or are considering to use it. If you don't (want to) do Spring, you can find [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView) another concrete kickoff examples which you could just copypaste and finetune/expand.

Another practices are listed in this [MyFaces FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Hibernate_And_MyFaces) (although MyFaces 1.2 targeted, this applies as good on Mojarra 1.x and 2.x).

Comment: Thanks, BalusC. Does it mean that I can't leave it the way it is with some code improvements?

Comment: You could, but it's only unnecessary code clutter and duplication and prone to problems in lazy loading and persisting objects with a relationship during a single request.

Comment: I think that the transactional part is a key part of the question and using the OSIV pattern would "solve" it as a kind of side effect. +1 anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: @Pascal: Thanks. The "major flaw in design" already made me to +1 yours :)